Metzora - with or without a Vav
Does anyone have any insight into why the name of the parasha Metzora is invariably written מצורע with a vav, while the word HaMetzora in the second passuk of the parasha from which the parasha name is derived is written המצרע without a vav?

"the name of the parasha Metzora is invariably written מצורע with a vav"  Can you support this claim?

Before I posted this question I looked in several chumashim (including Metsudah, Art Scroll and Chabad) and in several siddurim (including Singers, Koren and RCA) and in each of those siddurim or chumashim Metzora as a parasha name was written מצורע with a vav. Perhaps I should have said ALMOST INVARIABLY or USUALLY written מצורע with a vav

Whether invariably or almost invariably so written I am still intrigued by the question and would love to hear any insights or suggestions which respond to the question.

You could probably ask the same question about תולדות, קדושים, אמור, בחוקותי, בהעלותך, שופטים

You are correct, @Joel K. Thank you for pointing that out.

Which, taking @JoelK's point, provides the straightforward answer: when Hebrew is written (outside of the Torah's text itself) without nekudos, words are more usually spelled "full" to reduce ambiguity.

@Meir that may very well be the answer. It is certainly a most insightful point. Thank you.

In my view, two of the comments above together provide an answer:
"You could probably ask the same question about תולדות, קדושים, אמור, בחוקותי, בהעלותך, שופטים –
Joel K"
Apr 15 at 15:38
"... taking @JoelK's point, provides the straightforward answer: when Hebrew is written (outside of the Torah's text itself) without nekudos, words are more usually spelled "full" to reduce ambiguity."
Meir
Apr 15 at 16:41

What is this answer doing beyond copying two of the above comments? Did you mean to add to the text?

In my view those two comments provide an answer. I'll edit the answer accordingly.
